# How to specifiy formating of time string in azure pipeline build number

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

From the documention you can format the build number for the azure devops build pipeline but the formating on the time isn't working for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I want something like

YY.MM.DD.MMSS

`name: $(Date:yy).$(Date:MM).$(Date:dd).$(Hours)$(Minutes)`

However this will generate single digits like '20.08.12.150' for 3pm.  Does anyone know a way of forcing the format like the date fields so it will always be 2 chars?  $(Hours:hh)$(Minutes:mm) does not work; I did try that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of define the build number in `name:` of yaml file, you could add a powershell task to [update the build number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number) with command `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number`. Check the following example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Set-TimeZone -Id "China Standard Time"
      [string] $dateTime = (Get-Date -Format 'yy.MM.dd.HHmm')
      Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to '$dateTime'."
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$dateTime"
```

[image]